# Armar un MAP desde un LIST en Dart

Tags: lista, dart, map

Requiero su ayuda para armar un MAP, tengo una lista:

```
data = [
{"codigo_articulo":"0003","nombre_articulo":"HIGADO","peso_neto":"3044.80","importe_cigv":"15665.44"},
{"codigo_articulo":"0071","nombre_articulo":"PIERNAS C/E POLLO","peso_neto":"2688.20","importe_cigv":"10761.62"},
{"codigo_articulo":"0075","nombre_articulo":"PIERNA DE PAVO","peso_neto":"2053.40","importe_cigv":"26383.37"}
]
```

Y necesito armar un map con esta estructura (nombre_articulo : peso_neto):

```
map = {
"HIGADO" : 3044.80,
"PIERNAS C/E POLLO" : 2688.20,
"PIERNA DE PAVO" : 2053.40
}
```

mi objetivo es con ese map crear mi pie chart y me pide para los datos un map con la estructura que menciono. A ver si alguien me da una mano para armar esa estructura. Estoy usando para hacer el grafico  pie_chart: ^3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```js
const dataMap = new Map(data.map((v)=>{return Object.entries({[v.nombre_articulo]:v.peso_neto}).flatMap((v)=>v)}))
```

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta puede ayudar, considera añadir enunciados explicando cómo puede ayudar tu código

Comment: Hola he probado el codigo y me genera errores:  Error: New expression is not a constant expression.
  const dataMap = new Map(data.map((v)=>{
                  ^^^
lib/main.dart:11:23:
Error: Unexpected token 'return'.
                      return Object.entries({[v.nombre_articulo]:v.peso_neto}).flatMap((v)=>v);

Comment: Al parecer estas utilizando dart, es otro lenguaje y tu pregunta fue enfocada a JavaScript por la etiqueta. Tendrás que hacer su equivalente en el lenguaje que estas usando.

Comment: ok amigo, ya cambie la etiqueta. Gracias